# Is Zap A Card considered stealing if a keeper was taken from another player?

Tags: fluxx

In Batman Fluxx, if *Zap A Card* was used to take another player's keeper, is this considered stealing a keeper?

*Zap A Card* is an Action card with the following text:

> Choose any card in play anywhere on the table (except for the Basic Rules and any Meta Rules) and add it to your hand, unless the card you Zapped is a Creeper, in which case it goes in front of you.

Comment: To be clear, what's referring to "stealing a keeper" that needs to be tracked?

Comment: Another way of asking: in what situation in the game does it matter whether or not Zap a Card counts as "stealing a keeper"?

Comment: Do you have the wording for the card "Steal a Keeper?" I would think the ruling depends if the wording for both is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that "Steal a Keeper" is an Action card, and it tells you to put another player's Keeper in front of you, I'd say *no*. This card tells you to take any card and put it in your hand, which is also not considered in play.

Comment: But when used on "Zapped is a Creeper" it is placed in front of you. Which is the same action as "Steal a Keeper," but it is only relevant under this one set of conditions.

Comment: agreed. often times there are cards that give the same action but have different mechanisms. That seems like what's going on here. The result is the same but it's not stealing in this case unless the cards say it is stealing or unless the rules define stealing as any action that takes a card from someone else and places it in front of you.